# Verify signed file using GPG by passing in signature hosted online rather than stored locally (i.e. in keyring)?

Tags: encryption, pgp, public-key, digital-signature

Is it possible to pass the URL of a GnuPG signature when executing a verify query against a signed file?

For example, instead of:

```
gpg --verify file.txt
```

Is there a variation of something like:

```
gpg --import example.com/key.sig --verify file.txt
```

Obviously, you could import from a keyserver and append the line with `&&` followed by the verify but it doesn't quite serve my purpose so I'm wondering if anyone can suggest alternatives.

Comment: What about wget or a similar cli utility?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you try to achieve. The *signature* of a file is not imported! I split the answer to two parts, depending on what you actually wanted to achieve. I changed the example URI to reflect the actual use, but the file name does not matter to GnuPG at all.

### Not Importing a Key

When GnuPG verifies a signed file, it also verifies the *validity* of the key. This is an operation requiring the key to be in the keyring.

If you care about not having the keys verified against in your key ring, consider using another `$GNUPGHOME`, using something like

```
export GNUPGHOME=/tmp/gpg-verify
curl http://example.com/key.asc | gpg --import
gpg --verify file.txt
rm -r /tmp/gpg-verify
```

### Verifying Against a Detached Signature

If you want to load the (detached) signature from an URI, use curl and pipe the signature into `gpg`. From `man gpg`:

> `--verify`
>
> Assume that the first argument is a signed file or a detached signature and verify it without generating any output. With no arguments, the signature packet is  read  from `STDIN`.

The command line used would be something like

```
curl http://www.example.com/signature.asc | gpg --verify file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dash for the file that is supposed to be read from stdin:

```
curl -L https://exmple.com/file.txt.asc | gpg --verify - file.txt
curl -L https://exmple.com/file.txt | gpg --verify file.txt.asc -
```